# How to do a select with two parameters after the WHERE using PDO?

Tags: php, select, pdo

I try to select data from a database, but I'm unable to get it when I have two parameters after the WHERE.

Code that works:

```
$conn = null;
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'database';
$user = 'root';
$pwd  = 'root';

$auth = 'EP';
$nr = 2007;

try {
    $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);      
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT family FROM table WHERE nr = :nr');
    $stmt->execute(array('nr' => $nr));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

but when I use following select it doesn't work:

```
SELECT family FROM table WHERE auth = :auth AND nr = :nr
```

I think it's a problem in the line

```
    $stmt->execute(array('nr' => $nr));
```

When I do the following I have no result on the screen:

```
    $stmt->execute(array('nr' => $nr, 'auth' => $auth));
```

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error? Maybe you didn't have any row that matches with `nr` and `auth`, check the query too.

Comment: Olá @MarcioSimao no error at all!!!
Strange that when I write only:

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM publn_data WHERE publn_nr = :publn_nr');
$stmt->execute(array(':publn_nr' => $publnNr));

it works...

Alguma idéia?

Comment: Opa! Searching directly in your DB you get any result? Are you using a local or remote server?

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil what are the column names of the table ?

Comment: Hello @AncientGeek, the name of the columns are nr and auth.

Comment: @MarcioSimao, direct in phpMyAdmin it works. The select must be right.

Comment: Is there any other way to get data from the db using pdo? Do you guys know any example in the net which I could use?

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil  just try `var_dump($row)` without using while loop.

Comment: Apparently everything is okay, check if everything is okay with PHP installation and PDO drivers

Comment: Thank you all for your help! The problem was that what I searched was AB 2007, but the values were AB and 0002007. With only 2007 it worked in a SQL query in phpmyadmin and with mysqli as well. But somehow it doesn't work with pdo if we write only 2007 and not the entire value of the database field, namely 0002007. When I write EP and 0002007 it works fine. Thank you all again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My PDO Statement doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE THIS

```
stmt->execute(array('nr' => $nr, 'auth' => $auth));
```

TO

```
$stmt->execute(array(':nr' => $nr, ':auth' => $auth));
```

`:`  is a small typo error but PDO is Serious :( and the parameters will be empty.

Comment: This is incorrect - internally a colon will be added to the parameter if it's missing (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363)

Comment: @dave But if i didn't add a colon PHP throws error :( why would be that ?

Comment: Hey @AncientGeek, I followed you, but still no array on screen. Only when I use just $nr...

The select in phpmysql works just fine...

Comment: Example 2 of PHP Tutorial says the same: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php It should work. @dave in the Manual it shows the solution of Ancient Geek. Is this really incorrect as you say?

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil - I linked to the PHP source code - I'm 100% sure it adds the colon for you if it's not there.